# Javascript Keydown event works perfect in Firefox, Chrome but only once in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events, postback

I am developing a small questionnaire and fire an ASP LinkButton click when the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key is pressed from Javascript.

The Javascript is as follows:

```
 document.onkeydown = keydown;
    function keydown(event) {
        if (event.key == "Tab" || event.keyCode == 9 || event.which == 9 && !event.shiftKey)
            __doPostBack('<%=btnNext.UniqueID%>', '', true, '', '', false, true); 
        else if (!event) {
            if (window.event.keyCode == 9 && window.event.keyCode == 9 && !window.event.shiftKey)
                __doPostBack('<%=btnNext.UniqueID%>', '', true, '', '', false, true);
        }
    }
```

My ASP LinkButton looks like this:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="btnNext" runat="server" CausesValidation="true"></asp:LinkButton>
```

The LinkButton causes the page to reload with the next question. It all works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE.

In IE only the first <kbd>TAB</kbd> key press works, but when I then press <kbd>TAB</kbd> again the second time, after the next question was loaded, nothing happens.

Any idea how to make it work in IE? Hate these browser differences....

Comment: add return false at the end of function

Comment: @Webtecher It now works, but now all keys I press do a postback. How do I make it to fire only on the TAB key??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return false to cancel the default action caused by tabbing

```
document.onkeydown = keydown;
function keydown(event) {
    if(!event){
        event = window.event;
    }
    if (event.key == "Tab" || event.keyCode == 9 || event.which == 9 && !event.shiftKey){
        __doPostBack('<%=btnNext.UniqueID%>', '', true, '', '', false, true); 
        // Only capture tab events
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

(I have also [DRY'ed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) you code out a bit)

Comment: Thanks!! Now it works... had the return false in the wrong place.

Comment: I edited you answer so that text can still be entered on the page.

Comment: Noticed something else: Once I use the TAB key to navigate, the ASP LinkButtons do not work in Chrome and IE. Only Firefox they still work after TAB key press. Any ideas?

Comment: No sorry, I don't known anything about ASP.